# Watir text.include passes text that is hidden

Tags: ruby, angularjs, watir

I'm trying to validate that an error message is not visible on the screen.
I enter text into the text field, tab out of the field and then run the validation code. 
The text is not visible on the screen but it is still getting picked up as visible by Watir.

Here is my script:

```
browser.text_field(:id => 'name_first').set "test"
browser.button(:id => 'step_1_continue').click
sleep 1

if browser.text_field(:id => 'name_first', :class => 'form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required has-visited')
  print "First Name Validation Error Message Shows", "\n"
else
  print "First Name Validation Error Message Does Not Show", "\n"
end
```

Here is the code that is on the page.

Field is blank:

```
<input type="text" required="" maxlength="60" ng-model="Customer.First_Name" class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required has-visited" name="name_first" tabindex="1" id="name_first">
<span class="error ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="Error.Customer.First_Name">Please provide a first name.</span>
```

Field is not blank:

```
<input type="text" required="" maxlength="60" ng-model="Customer.First_Name" class="form-control input-sm has-visited ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" name="name_first" tabindex="1" id="name_first">
<span class="error ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="Error.Customer.First_Name">Please provide a first name.</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
browser.text_field(:id => 'name_first', :class => 'form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required has-visited')
```

Only creates a Watir element object. An object is consider to be truthy, which is why the `if` statement always validates to true and seems like the error message always appears.

You need to use one of the existence checks (see my book [Watirways](https://leanpub.com/watirways/read#leanpub-auto-existence) for more details):

- `.exists?` - Checks if the element is on the page.
- `.visible?` - Check if the element is visible.
- `.present?` - Checks if the element is on the page and visible.

Try adding `present?` to the `if` statement:

```
field= browser.text_field(:id => 'name_first', :class => 'form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required has-visited')
if field.present?
  print "First Name Validation Error Message Shows", "\n"
else
  print "First Name Validation Error Message Does Not Show", "\n"
end
```